# Trigger text message based on external webhook

Tags: twilio

Can I trigger a Twilio SMS from a webhook generated externally? In the documentation, I see most of the language about sending a SMS when a call comes in to a Twilio number but my question is related to triggering a Twilio event from an external event like a document upload in a cloud storage system.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, absolutely!

Whenever you receive the webhook (from any service you use) on your server, you just need to use Twilio's REST api to send the sms. [In the docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api) you can find several examples.

For example, let's say that you set up your cloud storage system with a webhook to invoke `https://my-super-cool-domain.com/webhooks/document-uploaded`. This url will be handled by some code in the language that you choose, i.e. asp.net mvc (c#). You could have the following code in the action that handles that url:

```
// Find your Account Sid and Token at twilio.com/console
const string accountSid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
const string authToken = "your_auth_token";

TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

var message = MessageResource.Create(
    body: "A new document has been uploaded to your cloud storage",
    from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("your_twilio_phone"),
    to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("recipient_phone")
);
```

Note: This uses .net client library, there are libraries for a bunch of languages, and if there isn't in the language that you use, you could just do the http requests, after all, it's a REST api.